# I run intelhaxm-android.exe, it gave me error

Tags: android, virtualization, intel

I tried to run my Android Studio application in my computer but got following informations:

> emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware
>   acceleration! Please ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and
>   usable. CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!

According to suggestion from website, I run intelhaxm-android.exe, it gave me following error:

> VT not supported This computer does not support Intel Virtualization
>   Technology (VT-x). HAXM cannot be installed. Please refer to the Intel
>   HAXM documentation for more information.

What I can do now? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like your CPU doesn't have Intel VT, which is a hardware feature that's not always available in all Intel CPUs. See following list.
http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology

If you do find your CPU in this list, then it's probably disabled by BIOS. Go into your BIOS settings and look for security settings, CPU or Intel to enable VT.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your information.

I have just found my computer system's processor is
Intel(R) Core(TM)2 Duo CPU E4400 @ 2.00GHz 2.00 GHz
In the list you suggested (http://ark.intel.com/Products/VirtualizationTechnology), I found the nearest item is 
Intel® Core™2 Duo Processor E4000 Series  E4300 E4400 E4500 E4600 E4700
which does not support Intel® VT-x.

Can you confurm that is true? And will you tell me I cannot run any Android emulator in my computer :(

Comment: Should I check BIOS settings and do something?

Comment: According to this http://ark.intel.com/products/29753/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-E4400-2M-Cache-2_00-GHz-800-MHz-FSB it looks like your CPU doesn't have Intel VT. (Ctrl + f Virtualization Technology).

Comment: However just to hold onto some hope. Open your BIOS settings and see if you spot anything there. Everyone's BIOS is a bit different, so I can't give you definitive guide on how to go into your BIOS settings. Please see if this guide helps http://www.sysprobs.com/disable-enable-virtualization-technology-bios A lot of older generation machines disabled Intel VT by default through BIOS for security reasons.

Comment: Hi,
 I have just downloaded havdetectiontool.exe from microsoft.com and it said: 
 This computer does not have hardware-assisted virtualization
 Should I throw away my computer?